# Generate long lived "User" access token from access token generated from Graph API Explorer. Not the app access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

My objective is to fetch public data from user timeline like statuses, feeds, username, hometown etc. I am using desktop application in Java which sends HTTP request with access token to get the timeline data. There are 2 types of tokens out of which one gives me complete data what i want and other gives me partial data. Both mentioned below.

**Type 1.** Generated on Graph API Explorer after clicking "Get Access Token" and giving the permissions

(This expires in 1 hour period and provides me all data what I want from user timeline like statuses, id, username, feeds etc.). For this I use below url and make HTTP call to API: `https://graph.facebook.com/<Username>?fields=id,name,statuses.fields(message)&access_token=AAACEd`
This gives me all the mentioned fields in the response JSON.

**Type 2.** Generated after creating app.

Using the appId & appSecret I generated a short lived access token.
(This expires in 1 hour period.) After this using the docs and url mentioned on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/ I am able to generate long lived access tokens (these expire in about 60 days).

When I use this token in the above url to authenticate, it doesn't resolve my objective and returns limited info from user timeline. It does not return "statuses" field and only few public feeds from the timeline.

The **problem** here is the access token which gives me all the data expires within an hour and is impossible for me to change it in my application after every hour manually, and the second access token which is long lived but does not give me complete data.

So I want Long lived User access token not app generated access token, which gives me all the data. i.e I want the long lived access token of type 1 described above. Process to extend the expiry time of the access token requires app id & secret but Graph API Explorer doesn't have the same.

Please suggest a way out to get the long lived access token of type 1 or any other way to get my objective fulfilled. Please help.

Comment: If you know that this API call requires an app id and an app secret – why are you calling it without them? If you do not have an app registered yet, do so first.

Comment: My basic concern is "What is the difference between User Access Token and App Access Token". Surely these are different as one returns me the desired data(User generated access token) and other returns very limited data(App access token).
I did what you are asking me to do but this doesn't resolve my objective and returns limited data. Whereas using user access token i am able to get what exactly I want but this token is short lived which i want to convert to Long lived. 
I want a way out to increase the expiry period of User access token.
Hope i am clear this time? Please help.

Comment: You are clear – sort of, because the document describing how to extend a user access token is also very clear IMO. So what’s your _actual_ problem in just doing what this document describes?

Comment: Hi.. I have edited my quest again as i was not allowed to answer my own question. Help me in getting the way out. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2015 you can now create a 60 day access token easily in Facebook.

Just click the Debug button on the user access token you want to extend on this page when logged in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

Then you will see a blue "Extend Access Token" button near the bottom of the page.